# AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone-5, avcapturesession

It seems that `AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification` event on iPhone 5 is triggered every time a AVCaptureSession is started.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(volumeChanged:) name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

Does anyone knows about how to fix this? I'm using this Observer to take photos with the volume buttons (I know it's a private API, but it's the same function of the default camera app, Apple usually turns a blind eye...), but *only on iPhone 5* a picture is taken every time camera starts.

Comment: Are you still having this problem? I would like to use `AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification`, but I don't have an iPhone 5 to test with.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I tried to fix this problem testing on iPhone5, but it seems to be very hard to do it :(

Comment: Did you find any good alternative way to detect volume button presses? (Besides the whole Audio Session listener method.)

Comment: No, at the moment. I simply deactivated the function for iPhone5 devices

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(volumeChanged:)
                                             name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

And then:

```
- (void)volumeChanged:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if([[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"AVSystemController_AudioVolumeChangeReasonNotificationParameter"] isEqualToString:@"ExplicitVolumeChange"])
    {
        float volume = [[[notification userInfo]
                         objectForKey:@"AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"]
                        floatValue];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I couldn't get it to work sensibly.  I'm sure there's a good reason Apple implemented things this way on the iPhone 5, but it's a damned nuisance.

The only way I found around it was to not use it, use the audio session property listener method instead:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //...
    AudioSessionInitialize(nil, nil, nil, nil);
    AudioSessionSetActive(YES);

    AudioSessionAddPropertyListener(kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareOutputVolume, volumeListenerCallbackIPhone, (__bridge void *)(self));
    //...
}
```

And then in the callback:

```
- (void)volumeChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"volumeChanged");
    // ...
}
```

...and then filter the event further there based on context.

-Ken

Comment: AudioSessionAddPropertyListener is deprecated in iOS 7.0 though I wasn't able to find alternatives.